# Terraform 0.13 - Modules, for_each and providers

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

**UPDATED**

I am trying to provision multiple SQL databases in Azure using Terraform.

My child module has the following code that provisions a SQL database:

**providers.tf**

```
// default provider
provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "main"
  features {}
}

// The provider that can access the storage account to store diagnostics
provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "storage_account"
  features {}
}
```

**sql_db.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "default" {
  name      = var.name
  base_name = var.base_name
  ...
  tags      = var.tags
  
  provider = azurerm.main
}
```

**data.tf**

```
data "azurerm_storage_account" "storage" {
  name = var.storage_account_name
  resource_group_name = var.storage_account_rg
  provider = azurerm.storage_account
}
```

I am calling this module in my **main.tf** file as follows where I want to provision multiple SQL databases using a `for_each`:

```
module "sql_db" {
  for_each = var.sql_db

  source = "...../sql_db.git"

  base_name = each.value.base_name
  name      = each.value.name

  providers = {
    azurerm.main = azurerm.main
    azurerm.storage_account = azurerm.storage_account
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  version  = "=2.20.0"
}

// default provider
provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "main"
  features {}
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "storage_account"
  features {}
}
```

When I run plan, I get the following error:

```bsh
Error: Module does not support for_each

  on main.tf line 35, in module "sql_db":
  35:   for_each = var.sql_db

Module "sql_db" cannot be used with for_each because it contains a nested
provider configuration for "azurerm.main", at
.terraform\modules\sql_db\providers.tf:2,10-19.

This module can be made compatible with for_each by changing it to receive all
of its provider configurations from the calling module, by using the
"providers" argument in the calling module block.


Error: Module does not support for_each

  on main.tf line 35, in module "sql_db":
  35:   for_each = var.sql_db

Module "sql_db" cannot be used with for_each because it contains a nested
provider configuration for "azurerm.storage_account", at
.terraform\modules\sql_db\providers.tf:8,10-19.

This module can be made compatible with for_each by changing it to receive all
of its provider configurations from the calling module, by using the
"providers" argument in the calling module block.
```

Comment: What is the structure of `var.sql_db`?

Comment: You've defined two providers in the module but only pass one of those modules in from the root module. The error is complaining about it not receiving all of the provider configuration from the calling module. Is there anything stopping you passing in the storage account provider as well?

Comment: I would remove `provider = azurerm.main` from `resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "default"` and set at `module.sql_db.providers` = `{ azurerm = azurerm.main }`. 

Unless you are passing other providers to the same module for different reasons.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. I am actually using multiple azurerm providers in the child module.

Comment: apparently they have fixed this in 0.15.x
see here: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/27739

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is, it's not supported. From the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/providers.html):

> A module containing its own provider configurations is not compatible with the for_each, count, and depends_on arguments that were introduced in Terraform v0.13.

HashiCorp has been absolutely adamant that providers can never be declared dynamically, which is why they allow neither a `for_each`/`count` within a `provider` block, nor a `for_each`/`count` on a module that contains a `provider` block.